# $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-}e^{(1/x)}(1 - \frac{x+2}{x^2})$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}e^{1/x}\left(1-\frac{x+2}{x^2}\right)$$
I tried to say that $t = 1/x$ but it doesnt work. Then I also tried Lhopital and got nowhere. Wolfram Mathematica also says that it cannot show step by step for this problem. Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: Why does $t = 1/x$ not work? Try it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=-1/x,$ so that we send $t$ towards positive infinity. Then we get $$\frac{-2t^2+t+1}{e^t}\,\to\,0.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y=e^{\frac{1}{x}} \left(1-\frac{x+2}{x^2}\right)\implies \log(y)=\frac{1}{x}+\log\left(1-\frac{x+2}{x^2}\right)$$
Using equivalents
$$\log\left(1-\frac{x+2}{x^2}\right)\sim -\frac{x+2}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{x^2}$$
$$\log(y) \sim -\frac{2}{x^2} \quad \to  -\infty \implies y \to 0$$